# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp( )

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Reloaded 0 libraries in 505ms.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following FirebaseException was thrown building Builder:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

## The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp file:///E:/Programs/flutterLearning/flash-chat-flutter/lib/main.dart:16:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:118:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:53:41)
#2      FirebaseAuth.instance (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:37:47)
#3      new _RegistrationScreenState (package:flash_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart:15:30)
#4      RegistrationScreen.createState (package:flash_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart:11:45)
...

Answer (score 0):

did you do this? in your `main()` you have to call `Firebase.initializeApp()`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GetStorage.init();
  await load();
  runApp(InitiateApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // You are missing this statement
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```